# IBM DB2 V7.2 ODBC Driver for Linux

Tags: db2, odbc

I am trying to connect to a client's DB2 v7.2 database in Linux.
I am pretty new to DB2 and could not find 7.2 odbc driver in IBM site. The earliest is 9.1 odbc driver. Is this compatible with v7.2 ?

Comment: please specify what DB2 you want to connect to ? DB2z, DB2i or DB2 LUW ?

Comment: Hi mshabou, my client only mention its a DB2 V7.2.5. There is nothing on DB2i or DB2z.
He did mention its install on a windows server 2003

Comment: try 9.1, usaly IBM DB2 client is backward compatible with N-2. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-fix-packs-version-ibm-data-server-client-packages

Comment: you find your answer page 42: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ps/products/db2/info/vr9/pdf/letter/en_US/db2ite90.pdf  (link to DB2 9 documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-version-91-linux-unix-and-windows-manuals)

Answer (score 0):

IBM does not make such old legacy drivers publicly available, for good reasons.

Genuine IBM customers always have a way to acquire legacy drivers however, although this is wholly dependent on who you know.

The v9.1 ODBC driver might have trouble accessing v7.2. It rather depends on which fixpacks are deployed (client and server), which operating-system (for client), and what authorization level you have for the target instance, and what rights you have at the workstation end, apart from the level of competence needed.  This is not work for beginners.

Keep in mind that legacy drivers may not be able to install on modern workstation operating-system versions (for example , they might need the workstation operating system to be also a legacy version).

Another approach is to have a detailed understanding of exactly how (with which versions and tools) the client currently connects to that legacy database, and then seek to emulate that mix of versions, possibly by cloning.